# OpenGL debug extension with glObjectLabel

Tags: debugging, opengl

I just starting to use the debug extension in my project but the glObjectLabel generates an error when used with GL_BUFFER.

Graphic card is a nVidia Quadro 600 with 340.82 drivers

This simple test is built with MSVC 2010 in 32bit :

```c
    #include <GL/glew.h>
    #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
    #include <iostream>

    void GLAPIENTRY ogl_cb(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar* message, const void* userParam)
    {
      using namespace std;
      cout << "message: "<< message << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
      using namespace std;

      if (!glfwInit())
      {
        cerr << "Error initializing GLFW" << endl;
        return 1;
      }

      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GL_TRUE);
      GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(1, 1, "", NULL, NULL);
      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

      GLint glew_result = glewInit();
      if (GLEW_OK != glew_result)
      {
        cerr << "Error initializing GLEW : " << (const char*)glewGetErrorString(glew_result) << endl;
        return 2;
      }

      cout << "VENDOR          : " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << endl;
      cout << "RENDERER        : " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << endl;
      cout << "VERSION         : " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
      cout << "GLSL VERSION    : " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << endl;

      glDebugMessageCallback(ogl_cb, NULL);
      glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
      glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);

      GLuint progid = glCreateProgram();
      glObjectLabel(GL_PROGRAM, progid, -1, "My program");

      GLuint bufid;
      glGenBuffers(1, &bufid);
      glObjectLabel(GL_BUFFER, bufid, -1, "My buffer");

      char prog_name[100];
      GLsizei prog_name_len = 0;
      glGetObjectLabel(GL_PROGRAM, progid, 100, &prog_name_len, prog_name);
      cout << "Program name " << prog_name_len << " : " << (prog_name_len ? prog_name : "NULL") << endl;

      char buf_name[100];
      GLsizei buf_name_len = 0;
      glGetObjectLabel(GL_BUFFER, bufid, 100, &buf_name_len, buf_name);
      cout << "Buffer name " << buf_name_len << " : " << (buf_name_len ? buf_name : "NULL") << endl;

      glfwDestroyWindow(window);
      glfwTerminate();
      return 0;
    }
```

And the output on machine :

```
VENDOR          : NVIDIA Corporation
RENDERER        : Quadro 600/PCIe/SSE2
VERSION         : 4.5.0 NVIDIA 340.82
GLSL VERSION    : 4.50 NVIDIA
message: GL_INVALID_VALUE error generated. ObjectLabel: unknown buffer object <name>
Program name 10 : My program
message: GL_INVALID_VALUE error generated. GetObjectLabel: unknown buffer object <name>
Buffer name 0 : NULL
```

Everything is OK with the program, but not the buffer...
Looking at samples from [www.g-truc.net](http://www.g-truc.net), and other on the net, I just can't seem what I do wrong...

Any clue on what is going on here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Object you assign label to must already be created. `glGenBuffers` only reserves names, without creating anything. `glCreateProgram`, on the contrary, generates one new name and creates program object.

Binding buffer object at least once would be enough.

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks !

Still, looking at the g-truc sample (https://github.com/g-truc/ogl-samples/blob/master/tests/gl-430-debug.cpp) line 136 :

    glGenBuffers(buffer::MAX, &BufferName[0]);
    glObjectLabel(GL_BUFFER, BufferName[buffer::ELEMENT], -1, "Element Array Buffer object");
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferName[buffer::ELEMENT]);

The label is set right after the generation, before the first bind.   How can this work ???

Comment: I suppose it could work on some GL implementations (I think if implementation decides to create object right in the moment of names generation - it isn't much of a violation), but it isn't required by spec, so you can't rely on that behaviour.